# What frontend softwares are available to use MySql in Mac OS (other than Base and Filemaker)?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using Mac OS 10.7. I was wondering if "Forms" (i.e. a layout for entering data which also includes fields for which values are retrieved via lookup based on data entered in some other fields on the same layout) could be created in MySql WorkBench? How exactly is MySql supposed to be used? 
Here's an image of the kind of layout I want to create for data entry. https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFXH1.jpg The left hand side fields are from Invoice Table and the right hand side fields are from Invoice Details Table linked via a relationship field based on Invoice ID. 
(PS: I do not want to use Filemaker)

Comment: Hello i think you should ammend your question as its very open ended. MySql is a Database which is used to store information and can be used to manage the data inside it. It is not a form maker. To create a form you will need to code it in some fasion either web based html/css or windowing based.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is a database engine. You can store and retrieve data to/from MySQL database.  MySQL Workbench is nothing more but a friendly user interface in front of it.  You cannot create any forms or layouts in it directly.  You can only enter data into one table at a time, using built-in user interface.

If you need to develop customer data entry forms, you will need to use one of a multitude of programming languages to write a program to do this.  Alternatively, there may be some frameworks out there capable of being customised to your needs.  However when you are dealing with more than one table, it's straight away more complicated than simply entering data into one table, because you need to keep track of and enforce referential integrity.

In any event, the answer to your question is "no, you cannot use MySQL Workbench to create forms".

Comment: what frontend options do i have to use MySql as backend? (other than Filemaker and Base)?